# Microsoft Graph API to access all email folders

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Right now I use V1 of [Microsoft rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/#GetMessageCollection)

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/MailFolders/INBOX/messages
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/MailFolders/SentItems/messages
```

If I wanted to get all messages in all folders, is there a way to do it in V1 of the REST API ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With outlook mail rest api v1.0 , there is no direct way to  get all messages in all folders , you could write your logic to loop the folders and get mails . But in v2.0 ,you could use below api to get a message collection from the entire mailbox of the signed-in user (including the Deleted Items and Clutter folders):

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages
```

Please refer to [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetMessages) for more details.